# Automapper .NET MVC SPA Angular 2 - how to merge configurations

Tags: model-view-controller, automapper

I have multiple tiers in my solution:

- Business
- Data (Data Factory with ability to choose ADO.NET or EntityFramework)
- REST (WebApi)
- Service
- Web (ASP.NET MVC Angular 2 SPA)

I want to map EntityFramework entities to the Business Entities (DTO) from Business layer (Data layer) and I also want to map Business Entities (DTO) from Business layer to the API Entities (WebApi layer)

WebApi project does not have a reference to the Data project.
Both Data and WebApi projects have reference to the Business project.

I have no previous experience working with AutoMapper.

If I initialize static AutoMapper in both Data and WebApi projects it apparently overrides static configuration and I lose mappings. Which is logical.

Data:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Section, SectionEntity>().ReverseMap();
});
```

WebApi:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<SectionEntity, ApiSection>().ForMember(dest => dest.Href, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SectionId.ToSectionHref())).ReverseMap();
    //cfg.CreateMap<Section, SectionEntity>().ReverseMap();
});
```

I noticed that in the AutoMapper Configuration guide there is a "Assembly Scanning" topic and example, but I just cannot make it work.

Is there a way for AutoMapper to "merge" configurations?

What would be the best way to merge mapping configurations from different class libraries without dependencies together?

Comment: What can't you make work with the assembly scanning? You just pass it assemblies or types within assemblies. The deployed application will have all the other assemblies in it, so this should be trivial.